# Ruby app and Resque: can't start workers

Tags: ruby, resque

I have this small ruby application, not Ruby on Rails - pure Ruby.

I've followed the instructions and I can queue stuff and see that everything is correctly queued using `resque-web`.

However, I have a problem to start a worker. The documentation indicates to run `bin/resque work` to launch a worker.

Doing so triggers the message `-bash: bin/resque: No such file or directory`

Everywhere on the Internet, people have the same problem, but for Rails app, not pure Ruby. The solution seems to include something in the rakefile, which I don't have.

How can I launch my worker? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key to solving your problem is rake.

Resque includes three rake tasks. All you need is a rakefile that requires `'resque/tasks'` to use them. When you ask Rake for its list of commands you'll see the three tasks that are included with Resque:

```
rake resque:failures:sort  # Sort the 'failed' queue for the redis_multi_queue failure backend
rake resque:work           # Start a Resque worker
rake resque:workers        # Start multiple Resque workers
```

The one you're looking for (to start one worker) is `resque:work`. You tell it which queue to listen to using the `QUEUE` environment variable. So starting your worker would be something like:

`QUEUE=your_queue_name rake resque:work`.

Alternatively, you can listen to all queues using `QUEUES=*`.

EDIT:

Here's a more complete example. Create a file called `rakefile`:

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque'

class Worker
  @queue = :default

  def self.perform(my_arg)
    puts my_arg
  end
end

task :hello do
    Resque.enqueue(Worker, 'hello')
end
```

Then in one terminal type `TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUE=default rake resque:work`. This will start the worker, watching the queue called **default**. It will print out any argument a job passes to its `perform` class method.

In a second terminal type `rake hello`. This will enqueue a job for the `Worker` class, passing the string `hello` as an argument (which will be passed to the `perform` method in the `Worker` class). It knows to push to the `default` queue by looking at the `@queue` property on `Worker`.

You'll see **hello** printed in the terminal where you started the worker.

This example doesn't do anything useful, and you wouldn't put all that in your rakefile, but I think it's a good starting point for you to start modifying it and build your own.

Comment: Thanks so much @wkjagt. It worked exactly as you mentioned and solved my problem.

Comment: Why do people type `TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUE=default rake resque:work` when it should be `rake resque:work TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUE=default`. Is this an old syntax thing? I had a hard time with this because the docs also reverse the order of the arguments after `rake resque:work` and put them in front.